# How to find the right libraryDependencies Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to find the right `libraryDependencies` of *sbt*. My scala version is `scalaVersion := "2.12.8"`

I tried like this but I got an error:

`libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" % "specs2_2.12.8-RC3" % "2.12.8"`

#### UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES

Answer (score 1):

You can add a double `%%` to detect automatically the version, as explained in the [SBT docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Getting+the+right+Scala+version+with):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-tools" %% "scala-stm" % "0.3"
```

or in your case:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.12.8"
```

Comment: I got this error 
`[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  :: org.scala-tools#scala-stm_2.12;0.3: not found`

Comment: In specs2, its says you need to add the following: `libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "4.3.4" % "test"` Check the installation page: https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.3.4/org.specs2.guide.Installation.html

Comment: Now I got another error :( `object apache is not a member of package org`

Comment: You need the Apache spark dependencies also, coul you post your build.sbt?

Comment: Would like to see your build file. Can you post it.

Comment: This is scala file `https://codeshare.io/G8eELA` It seems like libraries has not imported from *sbt* yet

Answer (score 0):

Also for example you have different assemblies for hadoop. 
For example Hortonworks, Cloudera etc. 
This companys have a repository and some time you must using them.

Example with hortonworks :

```
lazy val repositoriesSettings = Seq(
  resolvers += "Mvnrepository" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/",
  resolvers += "Hortonworks HDP" at "http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/",
  resolvers += "Hortonworks Other Dependencies" at "http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public",
  resolvers += "Atlassian oracle" at "https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-3rdparty/"
)
```